# Does equation $y = \sin(x - y)$ imply an analytical form $f$ which satisfies $y = f(x)$?

Tags: functions

Or is there a way to calculate an approximate value of $y$ of any given $x$?

The graph looks like this:

[y = sin(x - y) by WolframAlpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbE81.gif)

Sorry for my poor English. I'm learning WebGL now, then I want to draw something and then run into this equation. So what I really want is a way to calculate $y$ when a certain $x$ is given.

> #### Background: how did I get this equation
>
> I want to draw my [previous work](https://codepen.io/handsomeone/full/NArkYY) using WebGL. It is a group of circles implying an equiangular spiral . When using canvas2d, I calculate some circles then draw them by z-index order (a.k.a. rasterization). But in a fragment shader, I have to compute the color directly of any given coordinates (a.k.a. sampling).
>
> After mapping polar coordinates to Descartes coordinates, the image would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3yjM.png), the sine curves are circles and the implied line $y = x$ is the implied equiangular spiral in polar coordinates.
>
> The sine curves are just isolines, what I have to do is: for given coordinates, find out which sine curve it is on. So here the equation appears.
>
> Sorry for my poor English again.

Comment: If $x \approx y$, then $\sin(x-y) \approx x-y$ which yields $x = 2y$ for small $y$...

Comment: There's a solution with $f$ having period $2\pi$. You might be able to calculate a Fourier series for this function, though I don't really know how you'd go about it.

Comment: I did continue using up to $a_{19}$; it really improves the results up to $k=38$.

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know how good or bad this will be.*

Write $$y=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$$ Replace in the equation and expand as a Taylor series built at $x=0$. Identify the coefficients to get $a_{2n}=0$ and, for the first odd coefficients,
$$a_1=\frac{1}{2} \qquad a_3=-\frac{1}{96} \qquad a_5=-\frac{1}{1920} \qquad a_7=-\frac{43}{1290240}\qquad a_9=-\frac{223}{92897280}$$ We could continue for more terms.

Using $x=\frac{k \pi}{48}$, we get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 0.03272 &  0.03272 \\
 2 & 0.06543 &  0.06543 \\
 3 & 0.09810 &  0.09810 \\
 4 & 0.13071 &  0.13071 \\
 5 & 0.16326 &  0.16326 \\
 6 & 0.19571 &  0.19571 \\
 7 & 0.22806 &  0.22806 \\
 8 & 0.26028 &  0.26028 \\
 9 & 0.29236 &  0.29236 \\
 10 & 0.32426 &  0.32426 \\
 11 & 0.35598 &  0.35598 \\
 12 & 0.38749 &  0.38749 \\
 13 & 0.41876 &  0.41876 \\
 14 & 0.44978 &  0.44978 \\
 15 & 0.48051 &  0.48051 \\
 16 & 0.51093 &  0.51093 \\
 17 & 0.54101 &  0.54101 \\
 18 & 0.57072 &  0.57072 \\
 19 & 0.60002 &  0.60002 \\
 20 & 0.62889 &  0.62888 \\
 21 & 0.65727 &  0.65726 \\
 22 & 0.68514 &  0.68512 \\
 23 & 0.71244 &  0.71241 \\
 24 & 0.73912 &  0.73909 \\
 25 & 0.76513 &  0.76508 \\
 26 & 0.79042 &  0.79034 \\
 27 & 0.81492 &  0.81479 \\
 28 & 0.83855 &  0.83835 \\
 29 & 0.86124 &  0.86094 \\
 30 & 0.88290 &  0.88245 \\
 31 & 0.90344 &  0.90277 \\
 32 & 0.92276 &  0.92177 \\
 33 & 0.94073 &  0.93929 \\
 34 & 0.95722 &  0.95515 \\
 35 & 0.97210 &  0.96912 \\
 36 & 0.98521 &  0.98094 \\
 37 & 0.99636 &  0.99029 \\
 38 & 1.00537 &  0.99676 \\
 39 & 1.01202 &  0.99984 \\
 40 & 1.01607 &  0.99883 \\
 41 & 1.01726 &  0.99283 \\
 42 & 1.01528 &  0.98055 \\
 43 & 1.00982 &  0.96010 \\
 44 & 1.00052 &  0.92847 \\
 45 & 0.98697 &  0.88044 \\
 46 & 0.96873 &  0.80533 \\
 47 & 0.94533 &  0.67355
\end{array}
\right)$$

For a quite large range, this seems to work quite properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll have a try.